# (Horizontal)ScrollView or RecyclerView in this scenario?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scrollview, viewgroup

I have a list of complex objects. Each object has a lot of information that is being constantly updated from the backend webserver. I expect to normally work with 50-100 such objects.

Now, each object generates its own complicated widget. Widget architecture:

```
>Constraintlayout

-> 3 TextViews

-> SeekBar

-> 2 Guidelines

-> ConstraintLayout

--> LinearLayout

---> 1-6 FrameLayouts (share the same architecture)

----> LinearLayout

-----> 3 simple Views

----> 2 custom seekbars of different kinds
```

So if I have 100 objects, I have 100 of those widgets in a scrollable ViewGroup. Each widget databound to its object to visualize data from and pass to backend. This also means if I use RecyclerView, I have to set recyclable to false. What would be the better ViewGroup to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this situation I would go for RecyclerView along with that I would go for [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConcatAdapter`.

An Adapter implementation that presents the contents of multiple adapters in sequence.

[Sample](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a)

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that the ConcatAdapter is used for situations where contents fed into the adapter come from different sources? Im unsure why this type of adapter fits my situation, since I get all the information in 1 package from the webserver every 20ms. What am I missing?

Comment: The important thing is that the relevant data comes to the presentation. Creating an adapter for each data model and combining it with the concatadapter.

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid but I have no idea what thats supposed to mean. The widget has 1 data model. Its architecture may be complex but I inflate all its nested Views at the same time and address them by their IDs. I fill in the data in all of those Views at the same time and the source is the same package. I dont understand what "different data models" I have?

Comment: For example, consider 1 recycle view consisting of 3 different view types this can be created with 1 concat adapter. Consider 1 recylerview consisting of 4 different view types on the same screen. This can also be created with 1 concat adapter. This example can be achieved with a total of 2 concat adapters.

Comment: sample usage : https://medium.com/globant/merge-multiple-adapters-into-single-mergeadapter-c778b15a6020